SystemWebAdapters Remote Auth Doesnt Have Roles
I'm working on a .NET 4.7.2 conversion to .NET 8 using SystemWebAdapters for session and remote auth.
Currently auth is working and it shows that I'm logged in but if I try to use an authorize attribute with a role specified, it says I don't have access.  This is a role I do have on the .NET Framework side.
When looking at the context.User object I can see that I only have one Claim currently, does SystemWebAdapters not convert over Roles automatically?
Our legacy site is using MVC 5 with SimpleMembership and it specifies authentication mode="Forms"
We are using the membership tables in the database that they generated for us, I don't believe we customized it in any way.

I'm not an expert with auth or identity so I'm not sure how roles correspond to claims, so any help would be great understanding what is supposed to be happening as well as helping me figure out why it's not working would be great.
For more context:
.NET Framework Setup:

.NET 8 Setup:

As you can see on the Framework side I have 85 roles and it casts as a ClaimsPrincipal just fine:


But on the .NET 8 side, it shows that I'm logged in, but with no roles in my claims:

I have tested adding a role manually with Middleware and that does work and then authorize attributes work fine with a role specified like this: [Authorize(Roles = "Development")]



So it seems like everything is configured correctly on my end so that it would be compatible to work if the SystemWebAdapters package converted my roles to claims.  However, it is not adding them currently.

You can check whether the relationship between user and role in your dbo.webpages.roles and dbo.webpages.Usersinroles is correctly configured and whether there is relevant data?
In ASP.NET Core, the mapping between roles and claims is mainly implemented through the ClaimTypes.Role claim type. For information and configuration about roles and claims in asp.net core, you can refer to these two documents: Document1, Document2 .And you can try to get the role information from the database and add it to the user's claim when the user logs in:
Here are some sample codes for your reference:
private async Task SignInUser(string userName)
    {
        //var userRoles = GetUserRolesFromDatabase(userName);
        //Methods for getting user roles

        var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
};

        foreach (var role in userRoles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            //Setting authentication properties
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
    }



Thanks for the response.  This is a little trickier because I'm using SystemWebAdapters and Remote Auth, meaning the .NET Framework site is still controlling Auth, not the .NET Core site yet.  So I'm not sure how the IdentityUser would fit in until we fully convert from .NET Framework and convert over all of the membership tables.
With adding claims when the user logs in, that's on the Framework side also, I think SystemWebAdapters should be adding those claims for me but I'm not sure.

This is what i'm working with:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/inc/remote-authentication?view=aspnetcore-8.0

You can check whether the corresponding relationship between user and role is configured correctly. And Check whether the ClaimsPrincipal in your asp.net contains your role information.

Can you explain what you mean by checking the relationship between user and role?  Everything with roles works great on the Framework side, my user has 85 roles and authorization works great.  I tested casting HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal which then has 86 claims, one for the username and 85 roles, so everything seems setup correctly on the framework side.
On the .NET 8 side I tested adding a claim with middleware to see if roles are working and once I do that [Authorize(Roles = "Development")] works great.  But without the middleware my user only has 1 claim with the username.

I've updated my post with more details.
